# JSON wrong syntax

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm making my first chrome extension and I have a hard time with the manifest.
I have this code :

```
{
 "name": "Test Extension",
 "description": "JustforFun",
 "version": "1",
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*"],
 "background": {"page": "background.html","persistent": false },
 "browser_action": {"name":"Yellow Background","default_icon": "16x16.png"},
 "content_scripts": [ 
    {
    "matches": ["http://*/*"],
    "js" : ["inject.js"]
    } ]
}
```

My problem is that the content script doesn't get included in any page. Or maybe I'm doing it wrong.Should I see the content script included in the page source? And is it a problem if I left my `background.html` page empty at the time? I will put content in it but for now I'd like my content script to work. This is my content script by the way :

```
window.onload= function() {
    document.body.style.background = yellow;
}
```

Just a simple one that turns the background color to yellow when the page is loaded.

Comment: Maybe because you missed quotation marks? Try `document.body.style.background = "yellow";`

Comment: Ohhh...It works thank you very,very,very,very much...You have no idea how angry I was because it didn't worked...Thank you a lot!

Comment: You are welcome. Just pushed this as answer so the question doesn't persists as unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing quotation marks in inject.js

```
window.onload= function() {
    document.body.style.background = "yellow";
}
```